# Is This Differential Equation Homogeneous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is This Differential Equation Homogeneous? 
$$xdy = y( 1 + \ln y - \ln x )dx$$ because it is a problem from the book, and it is from the problems of "homogeneous DEs"

here are some of the steps i have made:
$$xdy-y(1+\ln y-\ln x)dx=0$$

$ydx+ylnydx-ylnxdx-xdy=0$ ; let $y = vx$, $dy = vdx +xdv$

$[xv+vx \ln(vx)-vx \ln(x)]dx - x(vdx+xdv) $
simplifying:

$[v \ln(vx)-v \ln(x)]dx-xdv$

i tried to separate it:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x}-\int \frac{dv}{v \ln(vx)-v \ln(x)}=0$$

what should I do so that it can become a variable separable? can anyone tell me where I've been mistaken? any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you

btw, the answer in the book is $y=xe^{cx}$

Comment: Fully answered there: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation#Homogeneous_type_of_first-order_differential_equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ADDITION**: Btw, you just had to use the fact that $v \ln(vx) - v \ln x = v \ln v + v \ln x - v \ln x = v \ln v $ and your solution lacks only this simplification.

**HINT**: Note that your equation can be rewritten this way

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y}{x} \cdot \left ( 1 + \ln{\frac{y}{x}} \right ) $$

Remember that equations of form $y^\prime = f \left (\frac{y}{x} \right )$ are homogeneous. So, you just have to proceed with usual substitution $ y(x) = x \cdot z(x) $.

Comment: Thank you for the help, mate :)